# java.util.ZipException when adding multidex true

Tags: android, android-multidex

Error:Execution failed for task **':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.**

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/api/client/http/AbstractHttpContent.class

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "dev.com.diaginfo"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.5.0'

compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.4.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}

compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.1.5'
compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2"

compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev35-1.22.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev13-1.22.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-tasks:v1-rev45-1.22.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have no idea how to deals with this error, it appears since i add

```
 defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: `multiDexEnabled true` doesn't actually completely enable multidex.

Comment: Hi,Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding entire `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'` library in dependencies then you're using split verison for `auth, identity` also. Refer to https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup for proper build dependencies .